# Read Numeric Values From text File that have been written in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, file, io

I need to be able to read the bytes from a file in android.

Everywhere I look, it seems that `FileInputStream` should be used to read bytes from a file but that is not what I want to do.

I want to be able to read a text file that contains (edit) **a textual representation of byte-wide numeric values** (/edit) that I want to save to an array.
An example of the text file I want to have converted to a byte array follows:

```
0x04 0xF2 0x33 0x21 0xAA
```

The final file will be much longer.  Using `FileInputStream` takes the values of each character where I want to save an array of length five to have the values listed above.
I want the array to be processed like:

```
ExampleArray[0] = (byte) 0x04;
ExampleArray[1] = (byte) 0xF2;
ExampleArray[2] = (byte) 0x33;
ExampleArray[3] = (byte) 0x21;
ExampleArray[4] = (byte) 0xAA;
```

Using `FileInputStream` on a text file returns the ASCII values of the characters and not the values I need written to the array.

Comment: not clear what you want

Comment: @Talls: Please, tell us what your actual requirement is! If it actally is to store the bytes **this** inefficiently, we'll help you with that. If not, we'll prevent you from doing a big mistake!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just **don't** store bytes as text. Never! 
Because 0x00 can be written as one byte in a file, or as a string, in this case (hex) taking up 4 times more space.
If you're required to do this, discuss how awful this decision would be!
I **will** edit my answer if you can provide a sensible reason though.

You would only save stuff as actual text, if:

- It is easier (not the case)
- It adds value (if an increase in filesize by over 4 (spaces count) adds value, then yes)
- If users should be able to edit the file (then you would omit the "0x"...)

You can write bytes like this:

```
public static void writeBytes(byte[] in, File file, boolean append) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file, append);
        fos.write(in);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null)
            fos.close();
    }
}
```

and read like this:

```
public static byte[] readBytes(File file) throws IOException {
    return readBytes(file, (int) file.length());
}

public static byte[] readBytes(File file, int length) throws IOException {
    byte[] content = new byte[length];
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        while (length > 0)
            length -= fis.read(content);
    } finally {
        if (fis != null)
            fis.close();
    }

    return content;
}
```

and therefore have:

```
public static void writeString(String in, File file, String charset, boolean append)
        throws IOException {
    writeBytes(in.getBytes(charset), file, append);
}

public static String readString(File file, String charset) throws IOException {
    return new String(readBytes(file), charset);
}
```

to write and read strings.

Note that I don't use the try-with-resource construct because Android's current Java source level is too low for that. :(

Comment: Bytes get stored as text all the time - when there's a desire that people can read them, when there's a desire to transition through channels that will not pass the entire binary codespace, when there's a desire to maintain framing...  Yes, it is inefficient, but that's not necessarily the most important factor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: But then, why with "0x" at the beginning and why without further structure like JSON or XML? I don't see a benefit in this way of storage. Only disadvantages... What do you mean by framing?

Comment: The reason for '0x' is to specify the radix, either for clarity, or because hex is not the only allowed option.  Kind of funny that you would complain about this overhead, and then mention JSON or XML.  Framing can be as simple as a newline to separate messages or records or chunks - something that's really not trivial to handle once you go pure binary.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Just that when you write pure bytes, you don't need any framing, because they are all equally sized... About JSON/XML: I'm okay with text formats. I just don't see a point in **this compromise** between binary and fully blown text format. Once again, knowing the real application would help a lot.

Comment: Pure bytes aren't necessarily interpreted in isolation.  In fact, you generally can't interpret them at all, unless you know that you are seeing the start of a perfectly transmitted message, or you know that they are encoded with in-band framing information, typically accomplished by reserving a few codes for that, and then escaping any occurrences - and that has the downside of making the length of the encoding data-dependent.  Sometimes it is just easier to use text.  At any rate, this is not an answer to the poster's question, and as a criticism of their system it is debatable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Which is why I asked the OP to clarify why he needs it. Because I just couldn't imagine a system that **requires** this compromise.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use FileInputStream.read(byte[] a) method which will transfer the bytes from file into byte array.

Comment: Turns out that the poster's actual desire was to do something different than it originally appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It seems I've misread the requirements. So the file contains the text representation of bytes.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(FILENAME));
String input;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    input = scanner.next();
    long number = Long.decode(input);
    // do something with the value
}
```

Old answer (obviously wrong for this case, but I'll leave it for posterity):

Use a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)'s [`read(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) method.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInoutStream(filename);
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

Comment: This returns ASCII bytes for the letters.  Instead of have an array of length 5, the array has 25 elements.